# How to send feedback/review/edit content in the Android Dev guide?

Tags: android

Is there any official/effective way for sending feedback for the Android Developer's guide? I noticed a mistake (a page recommends using a method that the documentation lists as deprecated) and was wondering if there is a way to point it out to someone working on the site, but I wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I don't know :) Here are some options :

If you want to get in touch with the guys from the dev rel team

- Android developers Google Groups -  Google employees from the [dev-rel team](http://code.google.com/team/) are active there.
- Our very [own chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android). I've seen the dev rel team drop by once in a while, especially during tools release announcements.

The much better way is to [submit a patch](http://source.android.com/source/submit-patches.html):

- The documentation is auto-generated from the source code. I'm not sure if these changes will be approved though :)

I'd really like to hear an official response for this one.

Comment: Thanks Reno, I'll give the patch a try. It's too bad that they make it so complicated/unclear for people to help out with the documentation.